# How to set 3d effect to UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, background-color

Hi i am try to set 3d effect to UIButton but my code does n't set properly.

it's come like this

[image]

but my requirement is like below

[image]

could you please help me some one.

My code is below:

```
self.submitBtn1.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"a53129"];
self.submitBtn1.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
self.submitBtn1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
self.submitBtn1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: check out UIButton layer shadow property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code to achieve this, set button type to custom

```
self.submitBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200.0f/255.0f) green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

self.submitBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;

self.submitBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
self.submitBtn.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

self.submitBtn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(100.0f/255.0f) green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
self.submitBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
self.submitBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
self.submitBtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
```

I am attaching image, shows result of this code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try playing around with the layer's shadow parameters. Like so:

```
self.submitBtn1.layer.shadowRadius = 5
self.submitBtn1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
self.submitBtn1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
```

Oh, and of course...

```
submitBtn1.setTitle(submitBtn1.currentTitle?.uppercaseString, forState: .Normal)
```

;)

Comment: hi thanks for your suggest code but it's showing shadow.that's not my requirement

Comment: @Anil, sorry, but it's hard to get what the requirements are based on the picture. I can distinguish the shadow, hence my code. But it's hard to figure out, what other effects are applied. Could you clarify it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Shadow is what makes the button look like a 3D object. Use this code below to get shadow for 3D like effect. Change to desired values, as per your requirements.

```
submitBtn1.layer.shadowRadius = 5
submitBtn1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
submitBtn1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
```